# VBA : error in creating pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create the pivot table in VBA( Excel 2013) using the following code

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim cache As PivotCache

Sheets("data").Select
Set cache=ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase,Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion)

Sheets("pivot").Select
Set pt = cache.CreatePivotTable("R4C")
```

I am getting error in the line **set pt**. please help in identifying the error.

Comment: Which Error? What have you tried already? Please visit [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The destination needs to be a range (you submitted a string)

Comment: Error is application-defined or object-defined error

I have used  **Set pt = cache.CreatePivotTable(Range("A1"))**, still it is giving error

Comment: works as long as there is no other pivot table... need to check that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right "RC"-string is valid... but you need full ref!

To make it work, use this:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim cache As PivotCache

Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Sheets("data").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion)

Set pt = cache.CreatePivotTable("'pivot'!R4C")
```

Pls check if there is another object at the destination (that may cause the error).